# How to Customize HTML5 Camera view?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, html5-video, html5-appcache

I know HTML5 camera api itself is not supported by most of the **mobile browsers**. What I am asking here is even less supported by **mobile browsers**.

AFAIK, options to capture image from **mobile browsers** using html5 are (let me know if any options are there even not supported by most of browsers not outdated like device tag)

1) using file input tag

`<input type="file" capture="camera" accept="image/*" id="cameraInput" name="cameraInput">`

2) Using navigator's getUserMedia

Now what I am looking for a way to customize camera preview for example drawing some circle/rectangle on top of camera view and read picth/roll values of camera sensor and turn that circle/rectangle to different color just before capture.

let me know the ways to proceed, any existing libs or demo codes are more useful.
I want to achieve only with HTML and some JS libs not looking for solution with Phonegap.

Comment: I actually looked into something similar to this a month or so ago, and determined its not currently feasible on mobile. On desktop you could use the users camera as an image src and do anything you want (but the mention of Phonegap says thats not what you want).

Comment: @ericjbasti can you please provide any links even related to desktop, I will try to pick some of it

Comment: here is a jsbin http://jsbin.com/fozojivuso/edit?html,js,output . View only http://jsbin.com/fozojivuso/ ... it won't work in Safari.

Comment: Any alternatives for Safari?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. According to Can I Use http://caniuse.com/#feat=stream , and reading a few Mailing list posts, it looks like the drafts of the spec have changed enough that it might not happen until things get finalized.